# Paypal chained payment 2nd receiver amout 0

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Hi I am developing a chained payment for a bookings portal, the I am facing following issue:

Sometimes the website owner is not charging any commission to some special clients, therefore the 2nd receiver (website owner) amount has to be 0 because the full booking amount is for the 1st receiver, but when I set the amount to 0 the API call responses with an error, there is a way to let know the `API` that in some cases there is going to be only one receiver ??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit a change payment with any of the receivers getting $0. The amount needs to be a positive value. If you're not going to send money to another party you should just use a Pay transaction.

Comment: thanks for your answer but dinamicaly could be a 2nd receiver or not because sometimes the commission for the 2nd receiver is 0 then the 1st receiver get the whole amount of the transaction